# What does "serial upvoting reversed" mean in the context of reputation?

Tags: support

I don't care about the reputation points. I'm wondering, "What was that?"

If it's an "adjustment" for something I did wrong, I'd like to know so I don't do it again.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with you personally.

It looks like yesterday one person went through some your questions and answers and gave you upvotes totalling 120 reputation points. This is considered by the system to be a form of (potential) voting fraud. I'm not sure if the limits have been made public but whatever they are the votes you received triggered the vote fraud script to reverse the votes from that person.

Answer (score 1):

If you get voted up for more than 40 rep I think within a certain time period by one person, you will get this revoked as it might be considered fraud (had this as well here)

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's >40 more like 70 is the trigger point.

Comment: I've already had 55 rep removed

Comment: It looks like it's event (rather than rep) driven. You for example have 9 events which occur in 2 minutes 8 of which are in the same minute (and total 55 rep). So it looks like the trigger point is ~7 events which means it could be as low as 35 and as high as 70. There may be a velocity component in the mix too even if it's just 7 events/day from the same user.